# How to get the set inside nested JsonNode using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a below JSON structure. which I need to parse using the Jackson library. I am building a web-service, which accept below JSON in a POST method's BODY.

```
{
    "organization": {
        "products": [
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "baz"
        ]
    },
    "mission" : "to be the best in domain"
}
```

Till, now I was having simple JSON body, which wasn't having nested and JSON element, like in this case `organization` is another JSON node which contains a Set of products.

This JSON keys are not mandatory, And I am accepting/storing `organization` JSON in `JsonNode`. And doing below checks.

1. If `organization` is null.
2. If `organization` is not null and it has `products` key.

But after that I don't know how to fetch the set of boards from this `JsonNode` and store it in Java's HashSet.

My expected O/P should be to have a set of boards extracted from my `organization` JsonNode.

P.S. :- I think I have to use the `ObjectMapper` but couldn't find a direct way of getting the Set. Looks like I need to use some JsonParser with which I am not very familier.

Comment: are you using it with any framework such as spring?

Comment: yes, I am using dropwizard, where jackson for json parsing comes by default.

Comment: can you show the code that you are doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create DTOs(Data Transfer Objects) for your purpose. The nested objects could have the structure as below:

```
class Organization {
    List<String> Products;
    .....
}

class WebOrganizationRequest {
    Organization organization;
    String mission;
}
```

By creating objects in this way you are mapping your JSON objects to classes and Jackson will typecast the JSON as an instance of WebOrganizationRequest when you pass it in the controller with WebOrganizationRequest as the request body type.

Comment: This way I already know, but this would require changes on code everytime, if I add another key to my `organization` which is nested JSON.

Comment: This is how generally it is processed and it comes out of the box in frameworks such as spring and dropwizard. Adding the elements to your organization class would let you know what parameters to expect in the request and add any validations etc if required. Generally, in API calls, we know what the controller should expect. so it should not be too much of a hassle to update code.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information, it would be great if you can provide some reference to what you are saying for more information.

Comment: You can find more information in the dropwizard documentation(https://www.dropwizard.io/1.1.4/docs/manual/core.html). You can see how they mapped the notification class in the post request body.  

To make things easier, you could also use Lombok(https://projectlombok.org/) which adds setter and getter methods to your classes using annotations and makes life easier.